# Pandas: 3 state boolean indexing with string replacement

Tags: string, pandas, dataframe, boolean, where-clause

I have a pandas dataframe that contains booleans (1 and -1) and nans.  I would like to populate it with the words "High", "Low", and nans.  I have tried:

**1) boolean indexing**

```
df[df==1] = 'High'
```

but then got a mixed type error when I went to the next condition,

**2) and using 'where'**

```
df.where(df==1,'High')
```

but this actually gives the opposite results (assigns 'High' to where df<>1).

How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) or double [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
d = {1:'High', -1:'Low'}
df = df.replace(d)
```

Another solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df == 1, 'High',
                  np.where(df == -1, 'Low', np.nan)), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
print (df)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,-1,np.nan],
                   'B':[np.nan,1,1],
                   'C':[1,-1,1]})

print (df)
     A    B  C
0  1.0  NaN  1
1 -1.0  1.0 -1
2  NaN  1.0  1

d = {1:'High', -1:'Low'}
df = df.replace(d)
print (df)
      A     B     C
0  High   NaN  High
1   Low  High   Low
2   NaN  High  High
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df == 1, 'High',
                  np.where(df == -1, 'Low', np.nan)), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
print (df)
      A     B     C
0  High   nan  High
1   Low  High   Low
2   nan  High  High
```